# In C++, what is wx.h?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

The existing code is calling some sort of **wx header file**  and my **DEV C++** compiler just says there's no such file.

Code:

```
#include<wx/wx.h>
```

Compiler error:

```
[Error] wx/wx.h: No such file or directory
```

So my question is -

1. What is `wx.h`
2. How do I install it in my compiler so that I can use it?
3. Do I need to change my compiler or DEV C++ would do fine?

Comment: Please do a bare minimum of research before posting on stackoverflow. This header is from the [wxwidgets library](https://www.wxwidgets.org/). You will need to download the library and configure your project to point to its headers and (link) libraries.

Answer (score 0):

> What is wx.h

It is the header file of a library. The GitHub project should have some instructions on how to fetch the dependencies and how to install them.

> How do I install it in my compiler so that I can use it?

Normally you have to download the dependency, build it (following some instructions), and then you need to use the header in your project and link the library. The exact steps depend on each library and each compiler.

> Do I need to change my compiler or DEV C++ would do fine?

In principle, no. Some libraries only work with some compilers, though.

Note that Dev-C++ is not a compiler, it is an IDE that comes with a port of GCC (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using WxWidgets framework but your compiler doesn't know where to find its headers, and apparently also libs which you would face with on a next step.

You, need to add to your compiler flags the output of `wx-config --cxxflags`. And also to your linker flags the output of `wx-config --libs`.

Assumption is of course that WxWidgets is installed on your PC